# Uploading Laravel from my localhost to godaddy server

Tags: php, laravel

My set up in localhost works well. I want to upload my Laravel app to my GoDaddy server. I created an FTP to transfer my Laravel app to my GoDaddy server. As what I've noticed upon creating my FTP account the files is inside /webroot so I created a `/webroot/testapp` inside `testapp` is my Laravel app. Inside Laravel app, there is a public folder. As what I've research in google other says only inside the public folder must be inside `/public_html` and Laravel app will be outside. in my case, it is `/webroot`. Now upon transferring my Laravel app to my server, I did not separate my public folder. I put it also in `testapp` folder because when I put the public folder outside my `testapp` folder and edit the index.php file my main site is in WordPress and it will cause an error. So I added the public folder into my `testapp` folder. When I tried to run in the browser it says 404 (Page Not Found) Error` so I tried to edit my index.php file below

```
<?php

/**
 * Laravel - A PHP Framework For Web Artisans
 *
 * @package  Laravel
 * @author   Taylor Otwell <taylor@laravel.com>
 */

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register The Auto Loader
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Composer provides a convenient, automatically generated class loader for
| our application. We just need to utilize it! We'll simply require it
| into the script here so that we don't have to worry about manual
| loading any of our classes later on. It feels great to relax.
|
*/

require __DIR__.'/../testapp/public/bootstrap/autoload.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Turn On The Lights
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| We need to illuminate PHP development, so let us turn on the lights.
| This bootstraps the framework and gets it ready for use, then it
| will load up this application so that we can run it and send
| the responses back to the browser and delight our users.
|
*/

$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../testapp/public/bootstrap/app.php';

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Run The Application
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Once we have the application, we can handle the incoming request
| through the kernel, and send the associated response back to
| the client's browser allowing them to enjoy the creative
| and wonderful application we have prepared for them.
|
*/

$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

$response = $kernel->handle(
    $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
);

$response->send();

$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Now can someone help me to work this thing out? I've seen it other tutorials is working well mine is not. Any help is muchly appreciated. TIA

Comment: have you tried with yourwebsite.com/public .. check if its working then i will give you htaccess code to make it root

Comment: i tried your answer but it will redirect to my main site

Comment: see my answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You should upload the whole project from localhost to godaddy and then ask from the support team to edit your hosts pointing to public folder.

This is a shared hosting service , so you can't do it alone. Ask it.

Comment: so you mean i will ask help from godaddy ?

Comment: yeap , when i had the same problem i asked them to point the vhost in the public folder. Only the support cant do this in a shared hosting.

Comment: but without asking help from godaddy? is that possible?

Comment: i think its not.

Comment: hi i already solve it! i just upgraded my php version in my hosting

Answer (score 0):

Crete .htaccess in root directory and add this below code:-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule    ^$    public/    [L]
RewriteRule    (.*) public/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I tried your answer the 404 page error is no longer there and now it points to my main hosting site

Comment: you mean i will create htaccess outside my laravel app testapp folder? or inside

Comment: you can create htaccess file where your env file there

Comment: yes i already created there. it still redirects to my main site

Comment: https://medium.com/@kunalnagar/deploying-laravel-5-on-godaddy-shared-hosting-888ec96f64cd

Comment: try these links if it helps

Comment: i tried your links this is what i get 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CLASS, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '$' in /home/content/87/10599987/html/awesome-project/index.php on line 50

Comment: line 50 code is this one
$kernel = $app->make(Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class);

Comment: youtube video has a reverse in windows tsk :(

Comment: Hi i already solve it! i just upgraded my php version in my hosting

Answer (score 0):

Follow this  [tutorial](https://medium.com/laravel-news/the-simple-guide-to-deploy-laravel-5-application-on-shared-hosting-1a8d0aee923e) it works for any shared hosting plan.